# poll the data from kafka as and when topic gets updated with new data

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a use case where I am streaming twitter data and storing it into kafka topic.
I want to show this data on UI as and when the topic gets updated. I am using websocket to get this. 
I am facing problem while fetching the data from the kafka topic. I am new to  kafka and am not sure how to get only the updated records from the topic.
Does setting the "auto.offset.reset" to "latest" solve my problem?
Please let me know if more information is needed to my question.

Adding my code..

```
public class ConsumerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

        ConsumerTest test = new ConsumerTest();
        test.startTwitterConsumer();

    }

    void startTwitterConsumer() throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.11.208:9092");
        props.put("group.id", "group-04691");
        props.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
        props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "500");
        props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
        props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
        props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        props.put("client.id", "w3l");
        props.put("max.poll.records", "500");


        KafkaConsumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
        List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> li;
        kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("dem"));

        ConsumerRecords<String, String> records;
        do{
            records =  kafkaConsumer.poll(1000);

            if(records.count()>0)
            {
                 //li = new ArrayList<>();
                for(ConsumerRecord<String, String>record:records){
                    System.out.println(record.offset());
                }
                kafkaConsumer.commitAsync();
                break;

            }else{
                System.out.println("No records");
            }
        }while(records.count()==0);
}
}
```

after executing this code each time I am getting the same offset values i.e., from 5 to 321.

Comment: Are you committing your offset after consuming from your consumer? So if you are committing the offset after consuming the record, Kafka will create a checkpoint for that particular consumer so when the next time you poll, you will get only the new records.

Comment: I have added my code with my question. I am still not getting the updated offsets.

Comment: Have you verified through a console consumer that there are more records in the topic? Also is the commitAsync() throwing some exception?

Comment: My consumer contains 75k+ records. And no exception is being thrown by commitAsync(). One things I noticed is while running the code for while(true), offsets are returned correctly.But when I put the condition as mentioned in the above code, poll runs for a single time and returns same data each time. I want  more control over fetching data.

Comment: The problem is with your while condition. When the loop executes for the first time, it populates the `records` list with data fetched from kafka, now the while condition breaks as the count > 0. I would recommend switching it back to `while(true)` and controlling the fetch via configuration. You can control with configs like max.poll.records, batch.size, etc

Comment: ok.. But what causes the while loop mentioned in the above code to return the same set of values and not the next or new values from kafka? Is it not being able to commit the offset?